# Cyrillic symbols in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text, cyrillic

I am writing a Java program with a GUI that will have Cyrillic text in some labels. When I create label  `JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Име на обект");` everything is fine and when my program starts it is also properly displayed. But I changed the PC I was working on and copied my project to my home PC. On that system, all Cyrillic text in my code now looks like `JLabel lbl = new JLabel("РћС‚ Р”Р°С‚Р°:*");` and is displayed in the same way when the program runs. How can I make Eclipse show my Cyrillic text normal again?

Comment: Have you tried using [UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-in-eclipse) for your Java files? That should solve your encoding issues.

Comment: sorry i dint noticed it was a link

Comment: Tried it but it is still the same :(

Comment: The encoding is probably already corrupted, and switching to UTF-8 won't magically fix it. Just re-type the Cyrillic text _after_ ensuring you're using Unicode (UTF-8) encoding, and then it should (hopefully) stay properly encoded after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same issue :)

Delete the file.
Copy the same file again.
Don't open the file.
Right Click on the file --> Properties.
Resource --> Text file encoding --> check "Other" with UTF-8.
Open the file.

Comment: In this case both the editor and the java compiler need to use the same encoding. That needs a bit more effort: workspace properties. The comments probably helped already. _Nevertheless useful for others._